# In ANTLR3, I need to discriminate between a 'comment' and a 'directive' (which looks like a comment)

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

I'm fairly new to ANTLR, and I've run into a problem.

I have a grammar I'm trying to write for a language that includes single-line comments and language directives that begin with the same comment identifier.  For example:

```
--This is a comment.  What follows is a directive with a parameter
--directive:param
```

A directive will always be in that format - two dash characters followed by a command, a colon, and a single parameter.

I would like to have the lexer ignore an actual comment (send it to the hidden channel), but tokenize the directives.  I have the following lexer rules:

```
DCOMMAND    : DATABASE;
fragment DATABASE   : D A T A B A S E;
fragment COMMENTSTART   : '--';
LINE_COMMENT    : COMMENTSTART ~(DCOMMAND|('\n'|'\r')*) {$channel=HIDDEN;};
fragment A  : ('a'|'A');
fragment B  : ('b'|'B');
fragment C  : ('c'|'C');
fragment D  : ('d'|'D');
....
```

There's only one directive for now: 'database'.  The DCOMMAND token will eventually represent several keywords potentially.  The problem is that my lexer is always shoving anything that starts with '--' into the hidden channel.  How do I make the LINE_COMMENT token not match directives?  Or will I have to move comment handling into the parser?

Comment: Can a comment start with `--This:`? In other words, is `--` followed by an identifier followed by `:` always reserved for directives?

Comment: The latter is true.  `-- This:` and `--This also:` should NOT be directives, however... note the whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to handle this in your lexer grammar without some manual code (which is IMHO better than promoting comments to the parser!).

What you could do is this:

- match `'--'`
- in a custom method, manually look ahead until the end of the line (EOL). Let this method return `true` when the `'--'` is part of a directive

  - if what you matched until the EOL looks to be a directive, do NOT match the characters and return `true`
  - if what you matched until the EOL isn't a directive, match the characters and return `false`
- if your custom method returned false, it must be a comment and you can `skip()` it

A quick demo:

```
grammar T;

@lexer::members {

  private boolean directiveAhead() throws MismatchedTokenException {

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    for(int ahead = 1; ; ahead++) {

      // Grab the next character from the input.
      int next = input.LA(ahead);

      // Check if we're at the EOL.
      if(next == -1 || next == '\r' || next == '\n') {
        break;
      }

      b.append((char)next);
    }

    if(b.toString().trim().matches("\\w+:\\w+")) {
      // Do NOT let the lexer consume all the characters, just return true!
      return true;
    }
    else {
      // Let the lexer consume all the characters!
      this.match(b.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
}

parse
 : directive EOF
 ;

directive
 : DIRECTIVE_START IDENTIFIER COL IDENTIFIER 
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
 ;

DIRECTIVE_START
 : '--' { if(!directiveAhead()) skip(); }
 ;

COL
 : ':'
 ;

SPACES
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for and you taught me something new about ANTLR in the process.  I really didn't want to muddle up my parser with the comment handling.